# how to handle this error in jquery library

Tags: jquery

I am using particular library for constrain on my textbox it giving me following error. How can I resolve it...

```
$.constrain usage:
//jquery.constrain.js: 5Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

link for library is at

http://jsfiddle.net/U9N63/

Comment: `$.constrain usage;` is certainly not valid Javascript. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: [Comment it all out](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/aGkMB/) or remove it altogether, apart from the licence. You don't need it. It's there just to explain how to use that plugin.

Comment: $(".title").constrain is not a function After commenting whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

add `//` before this line, looks like a part of a comment

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is not actually JavaScript code, but is a JavaScript *comment* excerpted from [this plugin source file](http://code.google.com/p/penny-pinching/source/browse/trunk/sqlite/static/jquery.constrain.js).  Note the `/*` and `*/` wrapping several lines of text at the top of that file.  Those character sequences represent the beginning and end of multi-line comments in JavaScript.  Most likely, your file is missing at least the opening `/*`.